# How to disable any optional feature in jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

How to disable any optional feature in jhipster such as "Kafka" rather than regenerating another Jhipster app from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `.yo-rc.json` file in your project, commit it, delete `src` folder and run `jhipster --with-entities`.

Of course, if you already have added custom code, you may want to do this in a git branch and use adequate git merging strategy like `git merge -s recursive -Xours <branch name>` to keep your changes